# How to move window out of display with wxpython on linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, wxpython, wxwidgets

i have a little GUI app, which runs on Windows 7 and 10 well. With self.Move(x,y) I can move the window, if x, or y is negative, part of my window or the whole window is out of screen. I want to achieve this behavior on Linux. On ubuntu 16.04 I tried on unity and kde, but it didnt work, the whole window is always visible. Can you show me way to move my window out of screen on linux?

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
#        kwds["pos"] = (10,10)
        self.frame = wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetTitle("Move around the screen")
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.location1 = wx.Point(-30,-100)
        self.location2 = wx.Point(500,500)
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.panel1, -1, label="Move", size=(80,25), pos=(10,10))
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnItem1Selected)
        self.Show()
        self.Move(self.location1)

    def OnItem1Selected(self, event):
        self.MoveAround()

    def MoveAround(self):
        curr_location = self.GetPosition() #or self.GetPositionTuple()
        if curr_location == self.location1:
            print ("moving to ", self.location2)
            self.Move(self.location2)
        else:
            print ("moving to ", self.location1)
            self.Move(self.location1) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Probably not possible per window manager policy. It would be impossible to click on the window and move it back to a visible position, for example.

Comment: On Windows it is possible and it is very useful, I'd switch to any window manager just to make this work.

Comment: Cant you just minimize it?

Comment: The fact that it is possible on Windows is irrelevant for X.. I don't know if any X window manager allows this; you have to experiment. But if I may make a suggestion: if all you want is to have the window out of the way but still possible to interact with it, why don't you create a system tray window/icon?

Comment: Why can't you just hide the window instead?

Comment: It is a toolbar/taskbar kind of thing. And If I hover over the visible part, it moves again to be fully on screen. I'll try some window managers :)

Comment: Have you considered `self.Iconize(True)`